# backbone.js Issue with module defining

Tags: javascript, module, backbone.js

I follow [this](http://weblog.bocoup.com/organizing-your-backbone-js-application-with-modules/) pattern to organize my js application.

As that example says our application should has the single entry point. File application.js doing that work.

```
// Filename: application.js

var chat = {
  // Create this closure to contain the cached modules
  module: function() {
    // Internal module cache.
    var modules = {};

    // Create a new module reference scaffold or load an
    // existing module.
    return function(name) {
      // If this module has already been created, return it.
      if (modules[name]) {
        return modules[name];
      }

      // Create a module and save it under this name
      return modules[name] = { Views: {} };
    };
  }()
};

// Using the jQuery ready event is excellent for ensuring all 
// code has been downloaded and evaluated and is ready to be 
// initialized. Treat this as your single entry point into the 
// application.
jQuery(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var foo = new Application.module('Chat').Collection();
 }); 
});


// Filename: chat-module.js

(function(chat){
  chat.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... }),
  chat.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ ... }),
})(Application.module('Chat'));
```

It seems well but if try to define chat module for example and invoke it later I have the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'Collection' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

I think that error due jQuery ready invokes when chat-module.js not available yet.
How can I resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code creates an object and assigns it to the global variable `chat`, which has a `module` function as a property:

```
var chat = {
    module: function...
};
```

...but then when you use it, you use `Application.module` rather than `chat.module`.

```
Application.module('Chat')
```

and

```
var foo = new Application.module('Chat').Collection();
```

It seems to me that your `chat` variable should be called `Application`.

Also note that you're using `module` in two different ways, both with `new` and without. *Without* would be the correct use based on your code. It will work both ways because `module` returns a function (which is an object), and so that will override the normal `new` behavior, but it means that using `new` serves no purpose and is misleading to someone reading the code.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake my application name is 'chat'. I have the following sequence of scripts loading: 1. application.js 2. chat-module.js. So jQuery ready invokes when chat-module.js not available yet. But I get that example from tutorial mentioned above.

Comment: @Erik: I think you've misunderstood my point. In `application.js`, you're creating a variable called `chat`, not `Application`. If you change `var chat = ...` to `var Application = ...` it may clear up your problem.